# Mean field theory = large-$N$ approximation?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, field-theory, ising-model, large-n

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/N_expansion) entry of $1/N$ expansion (or 't Hooft large-N expansion) mentions that

> *It (large-$N$) is also extensively used in condensed matter physics where it can be used to provide a rigorous basis for mean field theory.*

I would like reference(s) that reviews this connection between [MFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_field_theory) and large-$N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Adam's answer is excellent, and I'd rather make this a comment but can't as I just signed up in order to answer.

While I agree with most of what Adam said, there are cases where large-N works well for $N=1$. The case I'm familiar with is the large-N expansion for the "Spin Ices" Dy$_2$Ti$_2$O$_7$ and Ho$_2$Ti$_2$O$_7$, which have Ising spins on a pyrochlore lattice. The best reference for this is Sergei Isakov's [PhD thesis](http://su.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2:190643) (University of Stockholm 2004), specifically Section 4.3 and Subsection 4.8.2.

It's noted in that thesis that we shouldn't expect large-N to work for pyrochlores below $N=3$; the expansion is singular at $N=2$ owing to order-by-disorder. Extensive checking against Monte Carlo simulations and experiment verify that the expansion is good for $N=1$ (references given in the thesis), but we don't know why this is.

I found myself needing to prove the equivalence of large-N and MFT at high temperatures. I apologise if it's bad etiquette to reference one's own work, but I provide a mathematical proof in Section 2.4 of my Master's thesis which can be found [here](http://www.bristoltheory.org/static/uploads/peoplemedia/2014-01-21/Magnetic_Monopoles_in_Spin_Ice.pdf) (Perimeter Institute 2011).

I believe the main working difference between large-N and MFT is that MFT always contains a non-zero critical temperature $T_c$, but that $T_c\sim 1/N$ with $N$ the number of degrees of freedom at each lattice site. This means that large-N, with $N\rightarrow\infty$, has $T_c=0$ to zeroth order in the $1/N$ expansion (at which one generally works).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One question: in your case, are you talking about quantum Ising spins or classical spins ?

Answer (score 4):

Any good book on statistical field theory and critical phenomena will have a chapter on large N. See for instance Zinn-Justin's book.

Keep in mind that the large N approximation is a special kind of mean-field theory (since it is both self-consistent and exact in large $N$). It is thus quite different from the usual mean-field theory use for example in the case of the Ising model.

It is called mean-field because one only have to minimize the action without computing any corrections (which are of order $1/N$). But the equation is self-consistent, contrary to the usual mean-field theory.

To summarize : for the $O(N)$ model, with $N\to\infty$, one could use the usual mean-field, or the "large $N$ mean-field". The results would not be the same, as the former is approximate but the latter is exact.

In principle, you can also use the large $N$ results to finite $N$, even though it is not exact in that case (but sometimes $3\gg1$). But it definitely does not work for the Ising model ($N=1$). Indeed, the large $N$ approach use the fact that the Goldstone modes (the $\pi_i$) dominate the physics compare to the fluctuation of $\sigma$ (because there is an infinite number of Goldstone modes compare to one $\sigma$). But in the Ising case, the only mode is always gapped (away from criticality), so the results of the large $N$ is non-sense.

Comment: In Zinn-Justin's book, for example, I see a chapter on 1/N expansion of O(N) model and another chapter on MFT (steepest descent + corrections) of ferromagnetic Ising model, but not their equivalence. I want to see, for example, what 1/N expansion means for Ising model and its formal equivalence to MFT.

Comment: @crackjack: I have edited my answer. Tell me if that answer your question.

Comment: Also, I dont understand the fundamental role of Goldstone modes in large-N. I thought, large-N expansion of 2D O(N) models is a prototype example of how the fields can be massive (through the non-perturbative large-N resummation effect) while their action naively appears to be massless.

Comment: Thanks! It is much clearer now, except for last 4 lines: I was starting to warm up to the idea of an equivalence between large-N and MFT for Ising models. Zinn-Justin's book mentions (section 24.5 and A24.2) an expansion around MFT for Ising model, using $1/l$ as a parameter, with $ \beta \rightarrow l \beta $. Considering $N \sim l$ and $l \beta \sim N g^2$, I was reminded of an equivalence with 't Hooft large-N expansion. Also, with such a mean field expansion, the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry of Ising model becomes a spin variable with a gaussian distribution of spin values.

Comment: The difference is that $l$ is an arbitrary parameter, useful to organize the calculation, but in fact equal to $1$. $N$ is a real parameter (though usually equal to $1,2$ or $3$), which represents the internal degrees of freedom of the spin field. For Ising, $N=1$, and the field has one internal degree of freedom, corresponding to the field $\sigma$ and $N-1=0$ $\pi$ field. The large $N$ expansion is based on the dominance of the Goldstone fields $\pi$, so it will only give non sense for Ising.

Comment: For instance, in $d=2$, the large $N$ predict no ordered phase at low temperature, which is perfectly fine for $N\geq 3$, but misses the BKT phase for $N=2$ and the ferromagnetic phase for $N=1$ (cf Onsager solution of the Ising model).